# xml Path Parser does not recognise the part of xpath

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing

I need to resolve xpath where I have '[' the expression that follows.

```
<screenDef:InputScreenField Title="MyTitle"  Property="PayloadData[/spgp:ServiceProvider/rlc:ChildNode/rlc:movement/rlc:CMovementAmt[@Type = 'outstanding_loss_and_expense_for_contract_after_retention']/rlc:Amt].Value"  />
```

where property is being bind to the value of xpath using the indexer.

the problem is that the xml path parser method recognises the xpath till the first closing square brackets and does not include **/rlc:Amt**  part. Thus it does not give back any value but gives an exception stating that **/** not expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which tool you are using.
But quite sure you have to set the **namespace** for **the namespace prefix** `rlc`.